# How to create round shape models in Stage

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working with robot swarm simulation in Stage and I need some round shape models as obstacles.But after searching I only find out how to make polygon models by defining each vertex. 
Is there any method to make round shape models in Stage? Drawing a picture with round obstacles as a map may be feasible but that would be lack of extendability as my map scale may vary.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245454/how-to-create-round-shape-models-in-stage/) by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I guess it's impossible. I tried to draw a picture. The corresponding round obstacle in stage is made of a vast number of rectangular obstacles of different sizes. So I think round obstacle is not supported in stage.

---

Originally posted by [SilverBullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/20740/silverbullet/) with karma: 74 on 2016-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0